# DOMdocument: using nodeValue to change html content produces wrongly formatted html file ( &lt;div&gt; instead of <div>)

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am using jquery to let the user position various divs. Afterwards I'm dumping them to a php POST function via jquery's $.post and save them to an external html file through php. The .php file which should handle the writing uses DOMdocument (which I have never used- I also have no knowledge of any XML conventions, if there are any).

The .php file reads:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("startfile.html");
$doc->getElementById('container')->nodeValue = $data;
$doc->saveHTMLFile("endfile.html")
?>
```

It's really simple, and it should work. Howewer, whereas the endfile.html output should be:

```
<div id="container">
<div class= "dummydata">
</div>
</div>
```

it actually outputs

```
<div id="container">
 &lt;/class= "dummydata"&gt;
 &lt;/div&gt;
</div>
```

Which of course cannot be correctly parsed by the browser. I am sure I've been missing something simple and I'll feel extremely stupid once the solution is before my eyes. I don't want to resort to fopen/fwrite as this seemed like a very elegant and flexible way of handling html files.

**edit:** since the suggested XML fragment parsing kept failing due to unproper formatting (probably just cosmeting, seeing as i'm basically passing working HTML code - might it be XML is much more sensible in regard to spacing and characters used?- i went with this very hacky solution:

```
//write HTML with nodevalue
$doc->getElementById('container')->nodeValue = $data;
$doc->saveHTMLFile("../test.html");
//open file and replace stripped < and >s
$file_path ='../test.html'
$content = file_get_contents($file_path);
$content = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $content);
$content = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $content);
file_put_contents($file_path, $content);
```

It's not very elegant, but it works. Any thoughts? Do you think such a hacky solution might be justified instead of trying to properly format the HTML i'm passing as XML? And what are some possible pitfalls? I can't think of any, seeing i'm just cloning badly formatted but working HTML. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, [nodeValue](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#103012) will strip the tags.

You'll want to [create a fragment](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php) of the data, and then [append it](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php).

```
<?php

$data = '<div class="dummydata"></div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><div id="container">contents</div>');

$el = $doc->getElementById('container');

$children = $el->childNodes;
while ($children->length)
    $el->removeChild($children->item(0));

$frag = $el->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($data);
$el->appendChild($frag);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Be sure to replace the loadHTML and saveHTML with your code if you want to integrate it.

[Output](https://eval.in/private/31104d4ba40479):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><div id="container"><div class="dummydata"></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Dave! I already tried appending data (with good results) but i'm actually trying to replace the data in the "container" div and not append it (there is already data in div "container" which i would like to erase before adding "dummydata" to it). Any idea on how to do that? I tried replace child but can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: I believe the only changes required would be to change the loading and saving of the HTML (loadHTML/saveHTML -> loadHTMLFile/saveHTMLFile). There's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) on DOMDocument if you haven't read it already. There's also [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which is pretty popular on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simple-html-dom).

Comment: it seems to me like append XML is much more picky on formatting than a standard HTML injection. I am passing around 200 html lines via $post $data and the parser kept crashing (where as nodeValue had absolutely no problem.

So i ended up just bruteforcing it, with the code i added above: