# PHP, How to decode &lt;br /&gt to linebreaks without using saving as XML files

Tags: php, html, email-templates

I am currently writing a mail template for my website and sending it in with the help of php and pear mime_mail.
The html template is static and I change the mailbody and the mail title dynamicly in php. 
Here is how it is done :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
if(!$dom)
{}
$dom->loadHTMLFile("MailTemplate.html");
$itemtitle = $dom->getElementById("MailTitle");
$itembody = $dom->getElementById("MailBody");

$from = isset($_POST['from']) ? $_POST['from'] : '';
$to = isset($_POST['to']) ? $_POST['to'] : '';
$subject = isset($_POST['subject']) ? $_POST['subject'] : '';
$messagetemp = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';


ChromePhp::log($messagetemp);
$message = nl2br($messagetemp);
ChromePhp::log($message);

$newitemtitle = $dom->createElement('span');
$newitemtitle->setAttribute('id', 'newtitleid');
$newitemtitle->nodeValue = $subject;

$newitembody = $dom->createElement('span');
$newitembody->setAttribute('id', 'newbodyid');
$newitembody->nodeValue = $message;

$parentttile = $itemtitle->parentNode;
$parentttile->replaceChild($newitemtitle,$itemtitle);
$parentbody = $itembody->parentNode;
$parentbody->replaceChild($newitembody,$itembody);

$dom->saveHTMLFile("TempMailTemplate.html");

$boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());
$passage_ligne = "\r\n";
$headers = array('From' => $from, 'Subject' => $subject );

$mime = new Mail_mime($passage_ligne);
$html = file_get_contents("TempMailTemplate.html");

$text = $message;

$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html); 

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($headers);

$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
$result = $mail->send($to, $hdrs, $body);
ChromePhp::log($result);
```

I am able to change the content of the mail body and mail title, but I can't get any line breaks in my mail.

In the ChromePhp::log I am able to see the html var before changing and replacing the nodeValue of my DOM. 
First ChromePhp::log gives

```
hi
hi
```

Second ChromePhp:log gives (after nl2br)

```
hi<br />
hi
```

Then In my second mail template I get these line breaks characters  : hi<br />hi

Is there any way to force nodeValue or ReplaceChild taking html vars ? 
Or is there any way to prevent the use of SaveXml as I want to save my file to html ?

**EDIT**

```
As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876935/domdocument-using-nodevalue-to-change-html-content-produces-wrongly-formatted-h I could use this piece of code : 

$data = '<div class="dummydata"></div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><div id="container">contents</div>');

$el = $doc->getElementById('container');

$children = $el->childNodes;
while ($children->length)
    $el->removeChild($children->item(0));

$frag = $el->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML($data);
$el->appendChild($frag);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

But I new to append my data to a specific place defined by id:MailBody. I am searching for a appendXML command to a specific div container

Comment: check the formatting of your question. Are you getting html entities like `&gt;` per the question title? Because they're not showing up in your question, and it's not easy to be sure what you actually mean.

Comment: I am getting &gt; on the newitembody the one which has newitemid as an id attribute